# fusion table layer work with example but doesn't work with my own table

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I try to use google API V3 with google fusion table layer.
I have find an example here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple

When I paste this example in an editor HTLM all it work !

but when I want to create my own table with google table, and y replace the name of column location and the id of my table nothing work.

Map is load but any markers are display..

Thanks for your help

You can see below the code with my own table :

```
var map, layer;

function initialize() {
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(44.922896, -0.615849);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: chicago,
   zoom: 11
  });

   layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
  select: 'Location',
  from: '1gn80WesAXCFzuJ0E41l-5Y0odAnkCCdkYZ3oak0J'
}
 });
 layer.setMap(map);
  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But if  I replace by the example all it work :

```
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1mZ53Z70NsChnBMm-qEYmSDOvLXgrreLTkQUvvg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a message when I open the map ( https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1gn80WesAXCFzuJ0E41l-5Y0odAnkCCdkYZ3oak0J#map:id=3 )

The message should be clear:

**This map may not display correctly because the location column does not have map coordinates for all its rows.
Someone with edit privileges must geocode the column to fix this**

The `Location`-column contains adresses which must be geocoded before the markers may be drawn.

Go to File->Geocode to start the automatic geocoding.

Comment: I could see some markers on the map view, but still couldn't draw them with fusiontables layer. Is that the proper way to use a space separated field names?

Comment: Which space-separated field-names(there aren't any in your code)? I see the markers when I draw the layer.

Comment: Geocodable address has a space, but nevermind, I see escaped quotes do work fine

Comment: The column in your table is `Location`

Comment: Which one is my table? I'm not the OP. I just had the doubt about proper quoting "geocodable address"

Comment: @amenadiel: sorry, I didn't realize that you're not the OP. The table we are talking about is [1gn80WesAXCFzuJ0E41l-5Y0odAnkCCdkYZ3oak0J](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1gn80WesAXCFzuJ0E41l-5Y0odAnkCCdkYZ3oak0J#rows:id=1). However, the syntax `'\'Geocodable address\''` is correct when `Geocodable address` is the name of a single column (including spaces). Multiple column-names must be separated by comma.

Comment: it seems so, yes. It's weird. Most fusion tables syntax is SQL like, and field names should be enclosed either in backticks or double quotes, but in thid case only singles quotes seem to work.

Comment: It's documented here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#colName